# Find corners coordinates of color patch squares

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a photograph which contains a color calibration palette.
For each color-patch-square I want to obtain the pixel coordinate of the **top-left** square. Unfortunately, there is a perspective distortion in the photographs, so the grid is not perfect.

I have already tried Harris corner detector, and hough transformation to get the grid lines and then compute their intersections, however both results we're very unrobust and error prone.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to identify each color-patch-square individually? If you can identify each square individually you could create a mask (based on the color-patch-square) and use region props to find the corner. http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html you could possibly use `boundingbox` or `convex hull` to find the upper left coordinate

Comment: @andrew the question would be how to mask out the squares...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried googling for "Macbeth chart detector"? For example, one of the top results is this [dsp exchange answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/macbeth-color-chart-auto-detection), which has good links to solutions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11212584)

Comment: @FabioLamanna while this is not a really good answer, but it works without a link: "try a Macbeth chart detector". So it's not a link-only answer in the commonly used sense.

Comment: @FabioLamanna What are the "essential parts of the answer"? The OP's question is very general, probably because he/she did not bother ding even the minimum (google) amount of homework before crashing on SO. Detecting robustly a Macbeth chart takes a little more than running a Hough transform...

Comment: @FrancescoCallari well that is the second half of the usual argument. "No, it's not a link-only answer, don't delete it. Yes, it is an answer of bad quality, but mainly because the question was bad to begin with. Solution: downvote both, closevote the question, and try not to answer bad questions next time" :) (this problem [comes up often on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))